# MYSQL Selecting last 10 rows - group by column1 & sort by column2

Tags: mysql, group-by

Just to post here if someone will have the same problem.

### **Table:**

```
id | idp | ids
---+-----+-----
5  | 2   | 5
4  | 1   | 4
3  | 3   | 3
2  | 2   | 2
1  | 4   | 1
```

I set the `GROUP BY idp ORDER BY id` "didn't" affect results. I was trying to get last 10 rows grouped by idp sorted by id or ids. The problem is that last (first in table) row was grouped with forth row, and order was different.

### **SQL that works:**

```
SELECT idp, MAX(ids) AS max_ids
FROM table
GROUP BY idp
ORDER BY max_ids DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: you can order table(results) AFTER they were grouped. So 1st 4th row will become 'idp 2', 'ids 5'

Comment: Well here is the example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2941/2, there is option that I `GROUP BY ids` and results are in the right order. Example2: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2941/3.